# Scanning a single character in c

Tags: c, char, scanf

I have used the following code snippet to read several values but the single character constant variable *rating* is not accepting any value. It doesn't execute that particular `scanf` statement. How to resolve this?

```
char name[100],locality[100],vision[100],mission[100]; 
char rating; 
int dept,stud; 
printf("Enter college name\n"); 
scanf("%s",name); 
printf("Enter college locality\n"); 
scanf("%s",locality); 
printf("Enter college's vision\n"); 
scanf("%s",vision); 
printf(" Enter college's mission\n"); 
scanf("%s",mission); 
printf("Enter the number of departments\n"); 
scanf("%d",&dept); 
printf(" Enter student strength\n"); 
scanf("%d",&stud); 
printf(" Enter college rating\n"); 
scanf("%c",&rating); //not reading this value 
printf("%s\n%s\n",name,locality);
```

There is no compile error or run time error in this above code.

when I use the following code the variable is accepting value.

```
char rating;
printf(" Enter college rating\n"); 
scanf("%c",&rating);
```

Comment: `scanf("%c",&rating);` --> `scanf(" %c",&rating);`

Comment: First of all, your code does not compile because of  `'` in `Enter college's mission\n'`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It worked thanks. But why do we need to provide space?

Comment: for skip  white spaces(newline).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code except the printf statement of college's mission.